# Create an Action which accepts a function with return type

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I'm getting started in MVVM and WPF. I have a `CreateCommand` class from `ICommand` interface that accepts two Functions as arguments (One for Execute method and one for `CanExecute` method).

```
 class CreateCommand: ICommand
    {
        private Action ExecuteCommand;
        private Action CanExecuteCommand;
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public CreateCommand(Action executeAction,Action canExecuteAction)
        {
            ExecuteCommand = executeAction;

            CanExecuteCommand = canExecuteAction;

        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {

            // gives error that the function CanExecute expects return type to be bool
            return CanExecuteCommand();               
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            ExecuteCommand();
        }
    }
```

**Requirement**

I want to create a new command in my ViewModel like this.

```
        private ICommand _AddItemCmd;
        public ICommand AddItemCmd
        {
            get
            {
                if (_AddItemCmd == null)
                    _AddItemCmd = new CreateCommand(AddItemToList,IsProductItemEmpty);
                return _AddItemCmd;
            }
            set
            {
                _AddItemCmd = value;
            }
        }

        public void AddItemToList(){
           //My blah blah code
        }
        public bool IsProductItemEmpty(){
           //return true
           //OR
           //return false
        }
```

**Problem**

The compilation fails and it says CanExecute expects return type to be bool

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You answered your own question:
private Func<bool> CanExecuteCommand;

Comment: Thank you I thought it was tough. let me try this out. Thanks again

Comment: You can also use `Predicate<object> canExecute;` this allows you to pass in parameter to a function that already is returning `bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was pretty simple and straightforward. 
Just change the definition to

```
 private Func<bool> CanExecuteCommand;
```

**Thanks @LadderLogic**